# Action/ disaster movie about underground building rescue

Tags: identify-this-movie

I saw this movie in the 90s. Guessing from the production I would say it had a reasonable budget and was made in late 80s to mid 90s.

- **Language**: American/ English
- **Colour**: Yes
- **Live action**: Yes
- **Genre**: Action/ Rescue/
  Disaster
- **Location**: Inner city

I unfortunately don't remember a great deal, but I will try to give as much detail as possible. The film is based around a single building collapsing into the ground. I would say the building itself was considerably large/ multi-storey.

The difference of the collapse is the building falls into the ground but manages to stay well intact. Almost like a sink hole swallowed the building but stayed pretty much in one piece.

A lone hero is sent in to rescue as many people as possible battling obstacles and an unstable environment. I remember a scene with an elevator shaft and a body/ bodies being found. I believe the hero has to go fairly deep into the building to find survivors. I'm also pretty sure the majority of the story is set at night.

I think he gets a few people out but there is still one person left and has to go back for them. Maybe a young female I'm not 100% sure.

Hopefully some of it sounds familiar.

Comment: Daylight (1996) comes to mind but that was in a subway tunnel. Some of the scenes you describe seem familar though.

Comment: Daylight is a classic :) Unfortunately not the film I'm looking for. Thanks for the comment though!

Comment: Most of it fits [Trouble Shooters: Trapped Beneath the Earth](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0108397/combined) from 1993 (which is about rescuing people from a sinking building at night and features scenes in an elevator shaft), but it seems to be a *team* of rescuers, not a lone hero. See if the [trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jgtAhMQQw6s) rings any bells.

Comment: @Walt - thats the one :D  a few bits of the trailer look very familiar. The custom rescue team was where I got mixed up but was probably about 6 when I watched it. Maybe one of the guys goes it alone at one point. Anyway great stuff & many thanks! If you add it as an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's [Trouble Shooters: Trapped Beneath the Earth](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0108397/combined) from 1993 with 
Kris Kristofferson. From [TCM](http://www.tcm.com/tcmdb/title/475671/Trouble-Shooters-Trapped-Beneath-the-Earth/):

> A father-and-son team of rescue specialists work against the clock looking for survivors in a submerged building after an earthquake devastates a city.

The film takes place at night. Here's the trailer, which features them rescuing a girl and some scenes in an elevator shaft: